# CSS Background Image

Tags: css

I've asked this question before : [CSS Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890010/css-background-image)

Its not as such a repeated question though. In that I've now got a set image size of 1280 x 1024. But the problem I've got is that on larger screens the background etc dissapears. In the previous question it was suggested to try keep the elements fixed.

Does anyone have a solution for me on how to get this design to work on larger / smaller screen sizes? I've considered making the image 12 times and try find some JavaScript to get the browser size then start the background image based on that?

I'm aware of other issues on the page. I just want to get the background sorted first.

An example of my page is [HERE](http://www.stuartblackett.com/picturebook)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the background image from `body` and add it in html: `<img src="http://www.stuartblackett.com/picturebook/images/bg1.jpg" id="background" />`

Then in your css add the following:

`#background {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
}`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XW9Pz/

Comment: Thanks @Sotiris I've just read about this on another question. Its worth a try. Just to expand on that though, what would happen to the image if its a large screen, would it be pixelated?

Cheers

Comment: @stuBlackett you can see from what width and above start to have problem, and then you add `max-width` in your css.

Comment: excellent thanks. I will give that a try. I have asked the designer to turn the square frame into a rectangular one also. So that should clear a few issues.
How about Z-Index will that be an issue with overlaying stuff?

Comment: @stuBlackett, depends on the design. Give the lowest `z-index` value for the `#background` to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work to set

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

?

See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment

Comment: Would that not still mean the black background I've set still occurs though?